# Reverse for 'topic' not found. 'topic' is not a valid view function or pattern name (another one)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm aware that there are quite a few similar posts like this one, but I still can't figure it out.
This is the code in the 'topics' template that links each individual 'topic' to it (also the code causing the error):

```
<a href = "{% url 'topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
```

Error being:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'topic' not found. 'topic' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Here is urls.py:

```
urlpatterns=[
    #your paths go here
    path('', views.index, name='index'), # home page
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topics, name='topics') # add id arguemnt since each entry is linked to topic by id
]
```

Here is the topic function in views.py:

```
def topic(request):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added') # minus sign indicates reverse order
    context = {'topic':topic, 'entries':entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Comment: **Typo**: your url is named `topics` with an "s" while in the url tag you try to refer to `topic` without the "s".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at second path - you need name `topic`, not `topics`

```
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'), 
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic') <<<---THIS
```

And in `views` maybe with `topic_id`:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
```

Comment: Hello, I made the changes you suggested and I think it did fix that error, but I'm now getting a different error that says:

"Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']"

Do you know have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: yes, in `urls.py` you use `views.topics`, you need `views.topic` without 's'. If my answer helped you, mark it as the correct solution, it will help others as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm still getting the same error though ( Reverse for 'topic' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z'] ). I didn't specify earlier but it's from the topics.html template if that provides any more information

Comment: You can create a new question and describe the problem and attach your code `urls`, `views` and `html`